# "describe as [being] ADJ" - can "being" be omitted?

Tags: idioms, complementation

> Those will be the people that we could describe **as *being* elite**.

(Here I use *elite* for the adjective, but I'm interested in the general case with any other. For example "...*as being attractive*.")

Do I need ***being*** here? Can I just remove it and use the construction `as [adjective]`? In this case it would become—"...could describe **as elite**." What's the difference?

Comment: `elite` can be a noun.

Comment: @Stan: *elite* is not a mass noun, so it should be "as being **the** elite." I still can't say *I'm elite*" when *elite* is a noun.

Comment: Instinctively, I expect a noun after *describe as*. If it's not a noun, then it should be a verb-*ing*. However, because in English, you can use an adjective as a noun too, so it might be passable, but it might be better to quote the adjective, i.e. *... describe as "elite"*, and because *elite* can be either a noun or an adjective, I would say it's safer to say *... describe as elites*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. *. . . describe as elite* is fine.  It wouldn't usually be written with quotation marks.  Try searching for `describe as *.[jj]` in COCA, then click the top check mark to check all the examples and click "context". You'll see about a hundred examples, none of which use quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may omit the *being* in almost all circumstances, and it has no effect on the meaning.

The only situation I can think of in which you **must** use *being* is when you are describing a temporary behavior rather than enduring quality, just as you distinguish “John is being a jerk” from “John is a jerk”.

And the only situation I can think of in which you should **not** use *being* is when the complement is an active participle:

> <sup>ok</sup>The accident victim was described as walking with her head down.
>   <sup>∗</sup> The accident victim was described as being walking with her head down.

A little playing with Google Ngrams suggests that in the early 19th century the two versions were in pretty much free variation, but incidence of the *being* version has steadily declined since then to 5%-10% of the incidence of the version without *being*.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with Damkerng and I too **expect** a *noun* after *describe as*.

Nevertheless, if you use *being*, it suggests a little bit of *their efforts* of *being that!*. In other words, whenever we **describe** someone *being something*, we consider that they have actually maintained themselves (positive or negative) with their own efforts (remember, we often use *you are so kind. Thanks for being you.*)

> Those will be the people that we could describe as being elite (as elite) both means same but adding *being*, here in this case, is adding some appreciation to those people for maintaining themselves that way.)